# ngOption default selected option

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-services, angularjs-ng-options

How to have a default option in select box...I tried several options and do not get it

I tried creating a scope on my contralador with the value of the object that comes from json:

Like this:

```
$scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];
```

this my code:

**html:**

```
<select id="variant" class="form-control variant-select"
        ng-model="productSelect"
        ng-options="product as product.formattedPrice+' - '+product.variantQualifierName for product in item[0] track by product.url">
```

**JS:**

```
(function (){

  'use strict';

  /**
   * @ngdoc function
   * @name variantApp.controller:AppCtrl
   * @description
   * # AppCtrl
   * Controller of the variantApp
   */

   var app = angular.module('variantApp.product.variantCtrl', []);

   app.controller('AppCtrl',
    [
      '$scope',
      'ProductVariant',
      '$log',
      function ($scope, ProductVariant, $log){

      $scope.item = [
        ProductVariant.getData()
      ];

     $scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];

     $log.info($scope.productSelect);


   }]);

})(window, angular);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  `ng-options="product as product.formattedPrice+' - '+product.variantQualifierName for product in item[0] track by product.url"`
And `$scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];`

So either you're trying to select out of one option or you're initializing your productSelected to the same array.

Comment: Hi skubiski!

I've done this way because I need to have price and product name in the option text and And also I need to change the value of the option for the url of each product . (track by product.url) for set the value. I do not know if I can do otherwise :)

Comment: That is not what is wrong. Logically you're using the same list as your productSelected. Your productSelected or the model can be a reference to the list, sure, but in this case you need a product from that list.

Comment: Assuming   `ProductVariant.getData()` is returning an array there is no need to add it inside an array. `$scope.item = ProductVariant.getData();` will suffice. This will imply your iteration in ng-options will become `.. for product in item...` so that `$scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];` is indeed the first item of the item array.

Comment: Hi  skubski

Thanks for the explanation ! I understand . I've already solved that part .. but I still have the problem of having a product selected by default

Comment: Oki cool, now you need to verify that `ProductVariant.getData();` , like mentionned in an answer, isn't returning a promise before (e.g. a $http.get) actually sending a list of products. If this is happening , it would imply that `$scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];` is actually being set with **undefined**. This can be solved by resolving this code in a success handler, using the ng-init directive or ng-selected="$first".

Comment: Yep, as I mention, and @skubski re-iterated, if the `getData` call is a promise it is best to have the following initialization `$scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];` done in the success handler. In fact it would be best to have the list and the default selection in the handler if this is the case.
But I quite like the ng-selected="$first" approach as well. Although I don't know what the performance is like in terms of digest cycles with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

What you want ? To show a default option, please use

```
<select id="variant" class="form-control variant-select"
        ng-model="productSelect"
        ng-options="product as product.formattedPrice+' - '+product.variantQualifierName for product in item[0] track by product.url">
<option value="">Default</option>
</select>
```

Or to show a default selected value only then use:

`ng-selected="EXPRESSION"`. Like

```
<select id="variant" class="form-control variant-select"
        ng-model="productSelect"
        ng-options="product as product.formattedPrice+' - '+product.variantQualifierName for product in item[0] track by product.url" ng-selected="$first">
```

To show first value selected

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.

With the help of firebug and each of you and in special **skubski** I have resolved

The change I've made:

```
<select id="variant" class="form-control variant-select"
        ng-model="productSelect"
        ng-options="product as product.formattedPrice+' - '+product.variantQualifierName for product in item[0] track by product.url">
</select>
```

for this:

```
<select id="variant" class="form-control variant-select"
        ng-model="productSelect"
        ng-options="product as product.formattedPrice+' -     '+product.variantQualifierName for product in item track by product.url">
</select>
```

and

```
$scope.item = [
    ProductVariant.getData()
  ];

 $scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];
```

for this:

```
$scope.item = ProductVariant.getData();
$scope.productSelect =  $scope.item[0];
```

With these changes,  I 've gotten that one of the products is selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.item = [
    ProductVariant.getData()
  ];

 $scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];
```

If `ProductVariant.getData()` is a promise (async call), then `$scope.item[0];` could also be undefined at the stage that `$scope.productSelect = $scope.item[0];` is called.

Although as someone else mentioned there is also the strange fact that you are repeating over only the first index in the item list: `product in item[0]`